# How to check if a post id is different in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, post, codex

In order to check if a post id exist, i do this :

```
if ('publish' == get_post_status ($post_id)) {
    // do something
}
```

But how can i check if the id is different like in php :

```
if ($id != $var) {
    //do stuff
}
```

What i am doing :

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
if ($post_id != 835) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Is it correct ?

Comment: What do you mean, if the id is different? Different to what?

Comment: if post id is diffrent from a value (like 1, 10, 50, etc.) : if post id is different from 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using either of the following should work for you then. If the current post id **is not** 8 then print out "Not post 8". You can add an else statement if you want something else printed.

```
<?php
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    if ($post_id != "8") {
        echo "Not post 8";
    }
?>

<?php
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    if ($post_id != 8) {
        echo "Not post 8";
    }
?>
```